# Short story ID: All humans are very healthy and live for centuries. Doctor explains this treatment used to be a deadly, often fatal disease

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, medicine

I read this story about 15 or 20 years ago but from the style I suspect it was written some decades earlier.

Protagonist is an ordinary human being who does not know much about medicine. He goes to see his doctor as his treatment for incredible health and longevity is not working very well anymore.

The doctor examines him and tells him he needs a booster treatment to return to perfect health. The simple treatment is performed.

As they chat the doctor tells him that hundreds of years ago the treatment was originally an often deadly disease. It was called…

> Cancer.

Comment: It may be necessary to put a time frame on that story, because that's basically current events now. https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/t-cells-reprogrammed-to-slow-down-and-reverse-aging#Using-CAR-T-cell-therapy-to-reverse-aging

Comment: Thank you. I will add a timeframe. I had not heard this news.

Comment: Though the article is not an exact match with the story. It does not fit with the spoiler about the nature of the treatment.

Comment: I added the timeframe. 

Comment: I added the news article because your story managed to be harder science fiction than the author no doubt dreamed of. T cell therapy being modified from disease and cancer treatments to targeting aged cells is very consistent with the spoiler.  Of course this is just at mouse trial stage now.

Comment: Actually Judith I did miss that the vaccine WAS cancer twist ending. My brain automatically added a "for" cancer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Beyond Pandora](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55479) by Robert J. Martin.

It was published in 1962 so it was indeed written several decades before you read it. It's quite an obscure story having only been published in Analog magazine, an obscure anthology series and one collection of Martin's work. It is available on [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/23930).

It's only a couple of pages long, and the story is exactly as you describe. The story ends:

> At the door he paused and half turned to the doctor, "But say ... something I meant to ask you. This 'stuff' ... er, this vaccine ... where did it come from? Seems to me I heard somewhere that, way back before you fellows got it 'tamed' it was something else--dangerous. There was another name for it. Do you know what I mean?"
>
> The doctor's hand tightened on the doorknob. "Yes, I know," he said grimly, "but not many laymen remember. Just keep in mind what I told you. With any of these things, the pattern is protection, then control, then useful application." He turned to face his patient, "Back in the days before we put it to work for us--rebuilding tissue, almost ending aging and disease--the active basis for our vaccine caused a whole group of diseases, in itself."
>
> Returning the man's searching gaze, the doctor opened the door, "We've come a long way since then. You see," he said quietly, "in those days they called it 'cancer'."

Comment: Thank you, John. Another awesome identification.

Comment: @JudithJones There are a number of us hereabouts who grew up reading this era of SF stories. For us these are not _old_ stories :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie - Settle down, Granddad. You don't want to get riled up at your age.

Comment: You young whippersnapper!!

Comment: Wow. And you actually remembered this story from reading it in 1962? Or did you find it with some very clever choice of keywords?

Comment: @user14111 no, I was one year old in 1962 :-) I had a vague memory of having read it somewhere as a teenager and that was enough for me to Google it. As I Googled the results sparked up enough brain cells that I managed to narrow down the search terms.

Comment: I find I struggle to remember books I read last week, but I can clearly remember stories I read 50 years ago. Isn't getting old fun? :-)

Comment: Analog magazine scans https://www.luminist.org/archives/SF/AN.htm

Comment: Take it from me, kid, the joys of getting old are overrated. I was in grad school in 1962, not reading as much stf as I used to, and having lost interest in *Astoundalog* which had been going downhill in the 1950s.